# discordjs v14 buttonInteraction failed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

im try to create a discord suggest command but it failed with buttom click here is the code

```
        // Add event listeners for the collector
        collector.on('collect', async buttonInteraction => {
            if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'upvote_button') {
                upvotes++;
                upvoteButton.setLabel(` ${upvotes}`)
            } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'downvote_button') {
                downvotes++;
                downvoteButton.setLabel(` ${downvotes}`)
            }

            // Edit the original message to update the vote counts and disable the button that was clicked
            embed.fields[0].value = ` ${upvotes}`;
            embed.fields[1].value = ` ${downvotes}`;
            await buttonInteraction.edit({ embeds: [embed], components: [actionRow] });
        });
```